# Allocated object cannot be released in loop on seperate thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsthread

I have an `NSThread` that runs the following code:

```
for (Experiment *exp in experiments) {
    ExperimentBlock *block = [[ExperimentBlock alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, maxHeight, 310, 50)
                                                         experiment:exp
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(onExperimentButtonClicked:)];
    [scrollView addSubview:block];
    // block cannot be released for some inadequately explained reason
    maxHeight += 60;
}
```

Good memory management practice expects us to release any objects we have allocated, copied or new'ed.  However, when my thread finishes, if I have released (or autoreleased) the blocks I've added to my `UIScrollView`, the objects are displayed in my `UIScrollView` for a second before disappearing.

How should I release the memory without losing these objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must never modify a view (call `addSubview:`) on a background thread. This is why you're getting strange behaviors. You must call `addSubview:` on the main thread.

This type of work is typically much better done with GCD or `NSOperationQueue`. Manual `NSThread` is less efficient in most cases and more difficult to code correctly. You can move your `addSubview:` calls to the main queue like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.scrollView addSubview:block];
  [block release];
});
```

The call to `self` here is intentional. It creates a temporary retain loop that ensures we cannot be deallocated until this code runs.

Switching this project to ARC would simplify memory management here, and is recommended.